# Problem with SQLite3 and python using Pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter, pyinstaller

I've been writting some code to create an easy app to register products using `python 3.7.3` and `sqlite3` on debian. When I'm finally done, I tried to create an executable file from my script using pyinstaller. Everything was fine until I run the executable file by command using "./file" in the dist folder and there were 3 errors. On my sqlite database I used just a table called "product" but the terminal shows me:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: product
```

Additionally it shows me other messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "index.py", line 141, in <module>
File "index.py", line 47, in __init__
File "index.py", line 61, in get_products
File "index.py", line 52, in run_query"
```

On terminal I used this command to run pyinstaller :

```
pyinstaller --add-data "database.db:." index.py --onefile
```

Why my database is not recognized to run as onefile?
You can see my code on https://github.com/BraymNoodles/AppPythonProducts.git

Answer (score 2):

When you run the executable, it will decompress itself to a path like `_MEIxxxxx` (where xxxxx is a random number) inside temporary path (environment variable TEMP).  The file `database.db` is within that directory.

So if your code opens the database file like below:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
```

It will look for `database.db` in current directory, but it does not exist.  So a new `database.db` will be created and this causes the error mentioned in your question:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: product

because `database.db` is empty.

You need to get the temporary path by using below code:

```
import os
import sys
...
appdir = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
```

and open the database like below:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(os.path.join(appdir, 'database.db'))
```

You can read more information about the temporary path in PyInstaller [document](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html).

Answer (score 0):

```py
base_path = os.path.dirname("**sys.executable**")
conn sqlite3.connect(os.path.join(base_path, 'database.db')
```

Use this if you are trying to connect sqlite3 to a one file executable with no console.